# numbers instead of points in nivoslider

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

Does anyone know how to change the points to numbers in nivoslider?
I tried looking in the css and the code but I can't find anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just comment the `text-indent` and the image `background` from the Nivo CSS file:

```
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a {
    /*background: url("bullets.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
    border: 0 none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 3px;
   /* text-indent: -9999px; */
    width: 22px;
}
```

Explanation:

The numbers are dynamically generated inside the `<a>` 'bullets' but removed from viewport with `text-indent`. We just have to bring them in by commenting the lines I suggested.

Happy coding.